# Rotating Seating Algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I am planning a speed dating networking session with round tables. My challenge is to rotate all participants to each of the tables while minimizing the times in which they sit with the same person. The tables have a maximum seating capacity of 10. I am looking for a schedule (spreadsheet/formula) that shows the rotation schedule of each person. Thank you.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this problem? I am experiencing the exact same issue and was hoping you might be able to provide some guidance.

Comment: So I just found Perfect Table Plan (http://www.perfecttableplan.com/html/networking_events_seating.html) software that might solve this problem for me. I though I might mention it here. I've not tried it yet, but it looks promising.